# HTML Drag and Drop - determine position within object

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to determine the position within a div where the drop occurs (relative to the center point).
The goal would be to determine if the drop is above, below, right or left. So far, I can only find the coordinates of the event (SyntheticBaseEvent) clientX/Y, but not the coordinates of the target being dropped on.
Is there a way to determine this?

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can by getting the coordinates of the div and working from there

```
element.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Hope it helped